# How to decode scrapy responses? Scrapy response differs from Requests module response

Tags: python, utf-8, scrapy

I've been using scrapy for about 1 year and for the first time I'm facing an encoding problem. I don't use any arguments in the definitions for headers or cookies as I use an external proxy rotation service. And I've already verified that the request is done correctly (utf-8).

What happens is that when I make the request with the "requests" module I can get the source code correctly encoded/decoded and using a scrapy.Selector it is possible to get what I need. When I use scrapy I'm having problems with the decode, several special characters appear and I need to encode in latin-1 and again decode in utf-8:

```
    cache_response = response
    try:
        response = response.text.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
        response = Selector(text=response)
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error("Exception Encoding")
        response = cache_response
```

Scrapy vs requests (Same Headers):

Requests
`<li>Certificação energética:</li>`

Scrapy
`<li>CertificaÃ§Ã£o energÃ©tica:`

Scrapy `response.css('span[id="foo"]::text').get() -----> 107 mÂ² construÃ\xaddos, 64 mÂ² Ãºteis`

How can i make the response object come formatted correctly?

Comment: Python strings are Unicode already. They don't need decoding. This page is UTF8 too - almost all web sites use UTF8. `.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")` will mangle all characters outside the US-ASCII range. Remove these two calls

Comment: As for the second string you posted, that's a UTF8 string that was explicitly read using a non-UTF8 codepage, eg `latin-1`. UTF8 uses the same byte values as ASCII for the US-ASCII range and two or more bytes for any character above that. `ç` needs two bytes in UTF8. When those bytes are read using eg Latin1 they'll appear as `Ã§`. That's why you see `Ã` over and over - that's what the upper byte looks like in the Unicode range used for Western European characters

Comment: How did you make the Scrapy request?

Comment: I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70725298/235698) recently where the request was coming in like yours and adding a user agent header fixed the problem.  Maybe the same cause?  Not familiar with Scrapy so can't suggest the exact fix.